# How to preload video using link preload and match headers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, jsx, preload

I am trying to preload videos using [this technique from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/fast-playback-with-video-preload#link_preload) by using `<Link ref='preload'>`.

I have a simple React App here:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    videoUrl: null,
  };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.preloadVideo();
  };

  preloadVideo = () => {
    const link = document.createElement('link');

    const attributesAndValues = [{ key: 'rel', value: 'preload' }, { key: 'as', value: 'video' }];
    attributesAndValues.forEach(item => {
      link.setAttribute(item.key, item.value);
    });
    link.href = 'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4';

    document.body.appendChild(link);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <video controls src={this.state.url} />
        </header>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            this.setState({
              url: 'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4',
            })
          }
        >
          Set Video Url
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The app mounts, and `preloadVideo()` fires. And my sample-video gets downloaded.

However, when I click the `<button>` to add this video url to the video src, the headers are different:

> A preload for 'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4' is found, but is not used because the request headers do not match.

Each red box represents:

1. Initial preload.
2. Loading of video when `video src=""` is set via state.
3. Warning of using preload.

[image]

### Initial Preload Headers

[image]

### Video Load Headers

[image]

### MDN Documentation

After reading the [MDN Documentation on preloading content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content#The_basics). It says:

> preload has other advantages too. Using as to specify the type of content to be preloaded allows the browser to:
>
> - Prioritize resource loading more accurately.
> - Match future requests, reusing the same resource if appropriate.
> - Apply the correct content security policy to the resource.
> - Set the correct Accept request headers for it.

So how come my headers are different? Can you explicitly set headers?

Here's a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wky58pzk2w)

Comment: You should check your networks panel, because nothing is preloaded.
According to this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content#what_types_of_content_can_be_preloaded, the `link rel="preload"` doesn't work with videos.